# Error with function call CRegKey::QueryStringValue

Tags: c++, visual-c++, registry, atl

Today i found this strange error in querying the time zone information .
The code to read the display name of time zones looks like this

```
typedef struct {
    LONG Bias;
    LONG StandardBias;
    LONG DaylightBias;
    SYSTEMTIME StandardDate;
    SYSTEMTIME DaylightDate;
} TZI, * PTZI;

CRegKey RegKey;
CString regKey = _T("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Time Zones");
int idx = 0;
bool bMoreKeys = true;
bool bSuccess = true;
while (bMoreKeys && bSuccess) {
    CString sSubkeyName;
    DWORD nLength = 200;
    LPTSTR sBuffer = sSubkeyName.GetBufferSetLength(nLength);
    FILETIME ftLastWriteTime;
    bMoreKeys = (RegKey.EnumKey(idx, sBuffer, & nLength, & ftLastWriteTime) == ERROR_SUCCESS);
    sSubkeyName.ReleaseBuffer();
    if (!bMoreKeys) {
        bMoreKeys = false;
        break;
    }
    CString sSubKeyPath = regKey + _T("\\") + sSubkeyName;
    CRegKey subKey;
    if (subKey.Open(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, sSubKeyPath, KEY_READ) != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        //LOG_ERROR
        bSuccess = false;
        break;
    }
    // Get the display name
    CString sDispName;
    DWORD nDispBufferLength = 1000;
    LPTSTR sDispBuffer = sDispName.GetBufferSetLength(nDispBufferLength);
    if (subKey.QueryStringValue(_T("Display"), sDispBuffer, & nDispBufferLength) != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        //LOG_ERROR
        bSuccess = false;
        break;
    }
    sDispName.ReleaseBuffer();
    // Get the Bias (for later sorting);
    TZI tzi;
    nLength = sizeof(tzi);
    if (subKey.QueryBinaryValue(_T("TZI"), & tzi, & nLength) != ERROR_SUCCESS && nLength != sizeof(tzi)) {
        //LOG_ERROR
        bSuccess = false;
    }
    (void) subKey.Close();
    idx++;
}
```

But for some of the time zones for eg : argentina  the return value is not error_success.
On further debugging into the QueryStringValue , i found this

```
if ((nBytes % sizeof(TCHAR) != 0) || (pszValue[nBytes / sizeof(TCHAR) - 1] != 0)) {
    return ERROR_INVALID_DATA;
}
```

and when the nBytes size is **48** for any time zone display value then **always** error_invalid_data is returned .

To confirm this i have changed the regkey api call to

```
DWORD dwType = 0;
ULONG nBytes = 256 * sizeof(TCHAR);
TCHAR displayValue[256];
if (subKey.QueryValue(
    _T("Display"), & dwType, (LPBYTE) displayValue, & nBytes) == 0 && dwType == REG_SZ) {}
```

and i dont get the error anymore and everything is working fine .
Couldnt find out any valid reason that why it occurs.Anyone has better explanation why for all the timezones with size 48 we get the invalid data error .
Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

PS: In some machines everything is working well with the code mentioned above (i.e the first one) and in some other machines its not which is what really strange and with the second code everywhere i could see the code is working fine.

Comment: What is ATL or Visual Studio version?

Comment: I suppose you might be getting a different error, 234 `ERROR_MORE_DATA` if the actual value is longer than your buffer. The check you quoted looks good.

Comment: The funny part is after the return value error_invalid_data  if i call GetLastError then i get return value as ) which is no error. Thhis is really driving me crazy .

Comment: `GetLastError` is not applicable to this API, by design.

Comment: I can't reproduce. VS2010 Win32/x64 ANSI/Unicode using 1000. Perhaps a memory corruption in other parts of the code; Care to post the whole  loop?

Comment: I have posted the whole loop . Yes , you need to have luck to reproduce it . Since i have 10-15 systems here and everywhere this works fine except in one machine (where application software and OS is same for all these 15 systems) , can you believe this ? And this problem occurs only when i query for value 'Display' but not for others like 'Dlt' , 'Std' etc...

Comment: Can you post the loop with `TZI` and with `bSuccess`. The updated code does not reproduce the problem, neither in MBCS build nor in Unicode.

Comment: Done . Yes i know its hard to reproduce as my self couldn't do it in any other systems other than **particular one**. I am just looking for some convincing concept/answer that why it might fail sometime. As i said earlier i have a workaround by changing the method from QueryStringValue to QueryValue but still would like to know the root cause

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
CRegKey Key;
LONG nA = Key.Open(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, _T("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Time Zones\\Argentina Standard Time"), KEY_READ);
TCHAR pszValue[24];
ULONG nValueLength = _countof(pszValue);
LONG nB = Key.QueryStringValue(_T("Display"), pszValue, &nValueLength);
```

gets you a different error, 234, which is `ERROR_MORE_DATA` "More data is available."

This happens because the value itself does not fit fully into the provided buffer.

This is what you want instead:

```
CRegKey Key;
LONG nA = Key.Open(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, _T("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Time Zones\\Argentina Standard Time"), KEY_READ);
ULONG nValueLength = 0;
LONG nB = Key.QueryStringValue(_T("Display"), NULL, &nValueLength);
CString sValue;
if(nValueLength > 0)
{
    LONG nC = Key.QueryStringValue(_T("Display"), sValue.GetBufferSetLength(nValueLength - 1), &nValueLength);
}
```

Or, you need to provide large enough buffer, which you assume to be sufficient.

Comment: I have already provided the buffer size as 1000 , since none of the time zone display value will cross this limit and a pity is during the error scenario i get the length as 0 so i guess checking it with the last if condition which you have mentioned will still fail.

Answer (score 0):

The string in the reg may not be null-terminated. Hence the following validation fails:

```
if ((nBytes % sizeof(TCHAR) != 0) || (pszValue[nBytes / sizeof(TCHAR) -1] != 0))
{
    return ERROR_INVALID_DATA;
}
```

Note that it seems to be a bug in `CRegKey::QueryStringValue`, `RegQueryValueEx` allows to read not-null-terminated strings, and it is callers responsibility to handle this case. I had come across this exact issue in the code and had to replace the call to `CRegKey::QueryStringValue` with my own function.

Comment: Not really a bug, but a documented feature. From MSDN there is a note that says this under `CRegKey::QueryStringValue`: "Also, the RegQueryValueEx function used by this method **does not** explicitly **handle** strings which are **NULL terminated**. Both conditions should be checked for by the calling code."